# what's the type of 'struct random_data* buf'?

Tags: c++, types, declare

I'd like to have an instance variable of "struct random_data*" which are used in

```
int random_r(struct random_data *buf, int32_t *result);
```

I've tried declaring as

> "struct random_data* instanceBuf;"
>   "random_data* instanceBuf;"

but compiler doesn't like any of it.
How should I declare the variable?

-Edit

ah,, the api is for linux, and i'm on mac(bsd) :(

Oh wait, is it really linux only?
http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/BSD-Random.html

Comment: Have you included the *specific* header file where this struct `random_data` is defined? Or you've included some *random* header file? :D

Comment: What does "compiler doesn't like any of it" mean?  Does the compiler report "Error:  I don't like any of this!"

Comment: @James compiler says, random_data does not name a type(without 'struct') or field instanceBuf has incomplete type.   @Nawaz: I've included <stdlib.h>

Comment: @Eugene: As I said you've included a *random* header file, instead of the *specific* file which defines the `random_data`.

Comment: Voting to close: Premise of question is invalid. Asker was attempting to use a Linux function on a non-Linux environment. Problem had nothing to do with how to declare variables or how to include files.

Comment: how do i close this? just delete?

Answer (score 1):

Probably:

```
struct random_data buff;
int x = random_r (&buff, ...);
```

is the easiest solution. But you'll have to make sure that that structure has been defined.

And, if the buffer is required to be long lived (like a seed), make sure it's defined somewhere with a large scope (global or class-level, for example).

Comment: how do u declare "struct random_data buff;" inside class MyClass {}; so that it becomes an instance variable?

Comment: It's an instance variable by default. If you meant class variable, that's just a matter of prefixing it with static. But that may not be necessary, an instance variable may be just fine. What I was getting at was don't create it in a method fresh each time you want to use it.